# Calculating algorithm complexity of 1 2 4 8 pattern

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I need to calculate the complexity of this algorithm :

```
f=1;
x=2;

for(int i=1;i<=n;i*=2)
   for(int j=1;j<=i*i;j++)   
      if(j%i==0)
         for(int k=1;k<=j*i;k++)
             f=x*f;
```

I figured out the pattern and the summation of the inner loop which is i^2(i(i+1)/2)
but I can't get the summation of this pattern along the series of (1 2 4 8 16 ...)

So, how can I find the summation of this series?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to solve this for you (this looks like homework).  But here is a hint to simplify the problem.

This code:

```
for(int j=1; j<=i*i; j++)   
    if(j%i==0)
        // ... blah ...
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
for(int j=i; j<=i*i; j += i)
    // ... blah ...
```

Comment: thanks for your concern.. I understand what u mean .. my problem is in the math formula that I can user to do the summation of a serie of the form : 1 4 8 16 32 48 64 64 128 192 256 320 384 448 512 where n=8... as I said I figured out the formula of the inner series as n^2(n(n+1)/2) but I need the outer one..

Answer (score 1):

Another hint for the outer `for(int i=1;i<=n;i*=2)`: after each execution of the body of the `for` loop, *i* is multiplied with 2:

> 1 · 2 · 2 · … · 2

And this is repeated as long as the condition is true:

> 1 · 2 · 2 · … · 2 ≤ *n*

We can also write the repeated multiplication of 2’s as follows:

> 2 · 2 · … · 2 = 2<sup>*x*</sup> ≤ *n*

The number of times that *i* is multiplied with 2, i. e. *x*, can be calculated with the [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) to the base 2, i. e. log<sub>2</sub>(*n*):

> 2<sup>*x*</sup> ≤ *n*

With *x* = log<sub>2</sub>(*n*) it’s actually equal:

> 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(*n*)</sup> = *n*

Thus the `for` condition is floor(log<sub>2</sub>(*n*)) times true, so its complexity is Ο(log(*n*)), Ω(log(*n*)), and thus θ(log(*n*)).